# Hide element after time period without "shrinking effect"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I want to do:**

I want to hide an element or an image after a set time duration (e.g. 3 seconds). Unfortunately if I use the .hide(3000) method it has this "shrinking" effect. If I use the .fadeOut(3000) method it is of course fading out. I just want to display the element for 3 seconds (without any effect or smooth transition) and after these 3 seconds it should disappear instantly.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="buttonHide">Hide</button>
<img id="loadinggif" src="http://hosting-nation.ca/templates/hn1/images/loading.gif"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonHide").click(function(){
        $("#loadinggif").hide(3000);          //or fadeOut(3000)? Both doesn't have the desired effect. 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2LYa/6/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI: Your fiddle is not set up for jQuery.

Comment: ah, you're correct :). I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delay() with a zero value in hide() will work. The zero time will cause it to be an animation and delay pauses animations.

```
$("#loadinggif").delay(3000).hide(0);
```

Comment: setTimeout is more useful to the user since he will learn to use it to delay anything, while jQuery delay function is used mostly to delay animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407935/delay-and-settimeout

Comment: @Ahmad and adding the zero causes it to be an animation. Code is valid and it is your person opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the setTimeout() method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonHide").click(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
            $("#loadinggif").hide();  
        },3000); 
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to shrink, then use setTimeout() for 3 sec use CSS visibility as hidden. Check this fiidle below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".buttonHide").click(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
   $("#loadinggif").css('visibility','hidden');
          },3000); 
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2LYa/5/