# jQuery add a class after a delay then delay and a another class

Tags: jquery, css

How do I add a class after a delay then delay and a another class?

I can only seem to add one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".websites-container").delay(5000).queue(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $(".websites-container").delay(8000).queue(function() {
            $(this).addClass("gone")
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is this code located?  Is it within the ready event handler?

Comment: Sorry do you mean $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: Yup.  Is that where this is located or is it elsewhere?  Also just to make sure I understand correctly, the first delay's event fires, but the second doesn't?

Comment: Yes the first event fires but the scond one does not. It is in an extenal JS file.

Comment: jQuery's `delay` only works on animations, it's not a direct substitute for `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @adeneo see http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: @Scimonster - see https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/

Comment: And the correct way to do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ar7bbhnw/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`.dequeue()`](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) in the `.queue()` callback, otherwise the following items in the queue never get executed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".websites-container").delay(1000).queue(function() {
            // I'm impatient. I shortened the times.
            $(this).addClass("active").dequeue();
    }).delay(2000).queue(function() {
            $(this).addClass("gone");
    });
});
```

```css
.active {font-weight: bold}
.gone {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="websites-container">abc</div>
```

(This was almost solved by [@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697921/jquery-add-a-class-after-a-delay-then-delay-and-a-another-class/30698162#comment49454493_30697921), with the exception of placing dequeue in the callback.)

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the issue you're having is that you're using jQuery's delay feature incorrectly.  Take a look at this SO question for reference:  [.delay() and .setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407935/delay-and-settimeout)

Since we're not working with an animation or within an already existing jQuery queue you should be using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) in most cases:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".websites-container").addClass("active");
    }, 5000);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".websites-container").addClass("gone");
    }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: This is a valid use of `.delay()` though. See [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) for info on queuing custom functions.

Comment: I afraid I got an error in firebug "window.setTimeOut is not a function"

Comment: @rt840 It's `setTimeout`, with a lowercase O.

Comment: Ok this also worked when I changed the O to lowercase. Thank you JNYRanger and Scimonster.

Comment: @rt840 Yup, sorry about that typo was just writing a Java application so I had some camelCase stuck in my head.