# Delay not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a delay to the jQuery function so it loads after the page and javascript has fully loaded but it still loads just as if there was no delay.

```
$('.validate-state .select2-selection--single')
  .delay( 10000 )
  .addClass('custom-alert');
```

I am calling the above inside ready() function.

Comment: @mplungjan: What do you mean?

Comment: delay is usually used in animations

Comment: You can only apply delay to animation related functions. Use setTimeout instead

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTimeout` function, `delay` is usually used in animations

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('.validate-state .select2-selection--single')
  .addClass('custom-alert');
},10000);
```

if you want to execute the code after the js and html has loaded then you need to trigger your code in a page ready event

```
$(function(){
 $('.validate-state .select2-selection--single')
      .addClass('custom-alert');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

delay won't works on `.addClass` It can only affects the animations ; the way to do this is something like as quick example:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeOut( ()=>$(elem).addClass('custom-alert'), 1000 );
});
```

or the jQuery way :

```
$(function(){
    $(elem).delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass("custom-alert").dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To run your function after the whole page is loaded you can simply use `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.validate-state .select2-selection--single').addClass('custom-alert');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `setTimeout()` instead.

Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408036/5007419
Use `.delay()` for jQuery effects including animations.

`setTimeout()` is best used for everything else. For example when you need to trigger an event at a certain elapsed time.

Quick Example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // you code here
    }, 1000); // 1000 is time in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: I accidentally added this to @nullqube's answer. Sorry I'm new to stack and still learning how to post answers/replies..